# jQuery validation in different languages

Tags: jquery-validate

I've found a pretty good [jQuery Validation plugin](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation), it includes 
different languages ([in the localization folder](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/tree/master/src/localization)), however 
I haven't found a way to actually use them, how do I make it use German for instance?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I only needed to add the localization files after the validation plugin.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="localization/de.messages.js"> </script>
```

Comment: do you know where you can download these localizations from?

Comment: above link is dead, long live this link https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/tree/master/src/localization

Comment: Excuse me, I would like to know how to choose the localization according to the environnment. It seems that if I include the localization js files like this, for example, even if the browser uses English, the messages are still in German. thanks very much!

Comment: you can get the language via using a backend language (php,python,ruby) and put the "script" loading inside an if, alternatively the same can be done on JS with $.getScript

Answer (score 5):

After including `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.js"></script>` and your custom .js file in your html, ideally you would have your javascript file look something like this:

```
$.extend( $.validator.messages, {
 required: "Dieses Feld ist ein Pflichtfeld.",
 maxlength: $.validator.format( "Geben Sie bitte maximal {0} Zeichen ein." ),
 minlength: $.validator.format( "Geben Sie bitte mindestens {0} Zeichen ein." ),
 rangelength: $.validator.format( "Geben Sie bitte mindestens {0} und maximal {1} Zeichen ein." ),
 email: "Geben Sie bitte eine gültige E-Mail Adresse ein.",
 url: "Geben Sie bitte eine gültige URL ein.",
 date: "Bitte geben Sie ein gültiges Datum ein.",
 number: "Geben Sie bitte eine Nummer ein.",
 digits: "Geben Sie bitte nur Ziffern ein.",
 equalTo: "Bitte denselben Wert wiederholen.",
 range: $.validator.format( "Geben Sie bitte einen Wert zwischen {0} und {1} ein." ),
 max: $.validator.format( "Geben Sie bitte einen Wert kleiner oder gleich {0} ein." ),
 min: $.validator.format( "Geben Sie bitte einen Wert größer oder gleich {0} ein." ),
 creditcard: "Geben Sie bitte eine gültige Kreditkarten-Nummer ein."
});

$( "#id" ).validate({
 rules: {
  name: {
   required: true,
   email: true
  }
 },
 submitHandler: function(form) {
  form.submit();
 }
});
```

Other languages can be found here: [Localization](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/tree/master/src/localization)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but for someone looking how to exactly implement different languages, they can follow this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Javascript/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <xsl:if test="$LANG = 'es-mx'">
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Javascript/messages_es.js"></script>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$LANG = 'fr-ca'">
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Javascript/messages_fr.js"></script>
    </xsl:if>
```

By default, the error messages will be shown in English if non of the localization files are included in your webpage.