# How to make Jquery Validation Error Messages Dynamic?

Tags: php, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery validation in different languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618499/jquery-validation-in-different-languages)

I am using jquery.validate.js. And I need to show up the error messages in two languages. How can I do this? How can I make the error messages dynamic?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618499/jquery-validation-in-different-languages

Answer (score 1):

I use this for a dutch website. Just add this to a .js file and include it.

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
    required: "Dit is een verplicht veld.",
    remote: "Controleer dit veld.",
    email: "Vul hier een geldig email adres in.",
    url: "Vul hier een geldige URL in.",
    date: "Vul hier een geldige datum in.",
    dateISO: "Vul hier een geldige datum in (ISO).",
    number: "Vul hier een geldig nummer in.",
    digits: "Vul hier alleen nummers in.",
    creditcard: "Vul hier een geldig credit card nummer in.",
    equalTo: "Vul hier dezelfde waarde in.",
    accept: "Vul hier een waarde in met een geldige extensie.",
    maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("Vul hier maximaal {0} tekens in."),
    minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Vul hier minimaal {0} tekens in."),
    rangelength: jQuery.validator.format("Vul hier een waarde in van minimaal {0} en maximaal {1} tekens."),
    range: jQuery.validator.format("Vul hier een waarde in van minimaal {0} en maximaal {1}."),
    max: jQuery.validator.format("Vul hier een waarde in kleiner dan of gelijk aan {0}."),
    min: jQuery.validator.format("Vul hier een waarde in groter dan of gelijk aan {0}.")
});
```

To add a custom class use this:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    'class', function (value, element), 'message'
);
```