# How to localization jquery validation use with i18next?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova-3, i18next

I develop mobile app that user can select languages(english and khmer) that they want. But i don't know how to translate error message on jquery validation if user switch languge to khmer language?

Html code:

```
 <div data-role="content">                
                <div>
                    <center><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Resource Map"/></center>
                    <br>     
                </div>
                <p id="invalidmail" class="invalid">Invalid email or password.</p>
                <p id="noMailInDb" class="invalid">Not found in database.</p>
                <div><img src='img/ajax-loader.gif' class="loader"></div>
                <form id="form_login">
                    <h3 id="info_sign_in">Please sign in</h3>
                    <label for="email" data-i18n="global.email"> Email </label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="user[email]" class="required email"/>
                    <label for="password" data-i18n="global.password"> Password </label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="user[password]" class="required"/>
                    <center><button data-theme="e" id="btn_submitLogin" data-inset="true" data-i18n="login_page.login">Log in</button></center>
                </form>              
            </div>

js coding

Translation = {
  setLang: function(currentLang){
    localStorage['currentLang'] = currentLang;
    i18n.init({lng: currentLang}, function(){
        $(document.body).i18n();
    });
  },
  getLang: function(){
    return localStorage['currentLang'] ? localStorage['currentLang'] : "en";   
  },
  renderLang: function(){
    var langs = [{ value: "en", text: 'English' }, { value: "kh",  text: "ខ្មែរ" }];
    var currentLang = Translation.getLang();
    for(var i=0 ; i<langs.length; i++){
        if(langs[i].value === currentLang){
            langs[i].selected = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    var languageTemplate = Handlebars.compile($("#language-template").html());
    $('#div-language').html(languageTemplate({langs: langs}));
    $('#div-language').trigger("create");
  },
  translateLang: function(ele){
    Translation.setLang($('#' +ele).val());
  }


};
```

In type = "input" i can't translate because message come form jquery validation so i don't know how to translate this file to khmer language. Please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618499/jquery-validation-in-different-languages