# DateTime "must be a date" only with slashes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I use the following code I can only fill in (into an inputfield) as follows:

10/10/2014
i cannot fill in 
10-10-2014
on firefox

NOTE when using a RegularExpression, it will still give an error when NOT using forward slashes /
If the ReGex allows the - or any other symbol, C# itself will still give "must be a date"

Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Field is Required")]
[DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime Bday { get; set; }
```

Create.cshtml

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Bday)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Bday)
</div>
```

Comment: The problem iirc is with the client side validation, you need to install the localization for jquery validation and/or or override the standard validation.

Comment: Makes sense, How do i do this @Mark?

Comment: The only thing I know is that I have had this problem as well, but I can't remember how I fixed this, only that it had something to with jquery validation localization, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618499/jquery-validation-in-different-languages

Comment: Localization only seems to change the messages, I also included methods but it does not actually change the format from / to -

Comment: Look at - for example - the `methods_de.js` or `methods_nl.js` in the localization folder.

Comment: I've included both, "is not a date" still when filling in 10-10-2014

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, [`yy` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#yySpecifier) doesn't accept 4 digits year. It accepts only 2 digits of year.

Try to change your `DataFormatString` like;

```
DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}"
```

Comment: Edit: whenever i change a / to a - it instantly says "must be a date"

Comment: @EUDM Are you sure you add this exact format? Remember, `/` specifier has a special meaning. It replaces itself with your `CurrentCulture` `DateSeparator`.

Comment: Yes when i fill in 10/10/1990 it works but when i change the first - to (10-10/1990) it comes up with Must Be a date, then when i change the second one to  (10-10-1990) same error message

Comment: @EUDM But `10-10/1990` doesn't match with the format?

Comment: Yes, neither does 10-10-1990.
however 10/10/1990 works

Comment: @EUDM `10/10/1990` value works for `dd.MM.yyyy` format?

Comment: Yes 10/10/1990 does work, i said that 5 times now, haha